# Laravel Vue add Vue-router to component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I need to add a Vue router in the Laravel project with Vue 3. I have multiple components, which I'm using in Laravel blade but I need to add a router to only one of them(not to the whole Vue app). It's possible?

Thanks

**EDIT**:
I need to add router only to **OnlineView.vue** component.

**app.js**

```
import { createApp, defineAsyncComponent } from 'Vue';

const app = createApp({
    components: {
        ReferenceList: defineAsyncComponent(() =>
            import('./components/ReferenceList.vue')
        ),
        OnlineView: defineAsyncComponent(() =>
            import('./components/OnlineView.vue')
        ),
    },
});

app.mount('#app');
```

**OnlineView.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Router app</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { reactive, toRefs } from 'vue'

export default {
    setup () {
        const state = reactive({
            count: 0,
        })
    
        return {
            ...toRefs(state),
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**master.blade.php**

```
<main id="app">
    @yield('content')
</main>
```

**reference.blade.php**

```
...
    <reference-list />
...
```

**online.blade.php**

```
...
    <online-view />
...
```

Comment: Sure, it's perfectly possible. Just set your routes only the ones you need. Each one will target a specific component. If your question is more specific or you don't know how to do it, you should include the code you have tested and a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I edited the first post where I inserted the example code